# Persisting an Object Whose Base Class is Not @Entity

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, esper

I have a case where I would like to persist objects of a class from a third-party library. More specifically I would like to persist objects of type [EPStatementObjectModel](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.10.0/doc/api/com/espertech/esper/client/soda/EPStatementObjectModel.html).

As far as I am aware this class is not marked as [@javax.persistence.Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) but does implement Serializable but as it stands I cannot directly persist this class. If I understand persisting objects correctly, the top-level class must be the 'entity' class. Does this mean that my only way to persist this class is to use XML descriptors, (which I would like to avoid)?

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306438/persisting-3rd-party-objects-with-jpa :)

Comment: This implies I need to know something of the internals of the third-party class?

Comment: i think yes, but i didnt have these use case before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can use xml mappings in `orm.xml` file as suggested by pL4Gu33 in a comment under your question. This approach has one drawback - it requires `EPStatementObjectModel` class to have some kind of unique identifier - and as I can see it does not have public one.
2. You can also extend `EPStatementObjectModel` class (as it is not final) and wrap all getters and setter in your own setter/getter methods. In this case you can freely add some fields to class such as unique identifier. Using this approach enables you to make use of annotations. It will be easy to use entities retreived from database in places where `EPStatementObjectModel` object is needed (up-casting), unfortunately persisting existing `EPStatementObjectModel` objects will be more difficult as you will have to transform them in your subclass (down-casting) - therefore it would be nice to implement something like copy constructor.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using XML but it does seem the best solution for third-party classes although I didn't realise it would need a unique identifier. I do have the source code for the classes and would prefer to use annotations if possible and your second suggestion does seem the way forward however don't I also need a unique identifier in this case?

Comment: @Kerry As in every entity you need some sort of unique identifier (`uid`) which allows you to retrieve (also set as a part of relationship) this entity from database. In both solutions you would need such `uid` - maybe it can be some field from this class (I don't really know any usage of this class, so I cannot say if it already has `uid` or not). The plus of the second approach is (apart from using annotations) an ability to easily create a field in the subclass which would play as `uid`.

Comment: I've just realised I do not need to subclass EPStatementObjectModel. As it implements `Serializable` all I need to do is place it in a container Entity class and mark it as `@Lob`.

Comment: @Kerry it depends on how you will use it, storing objects as `@Lob` makes it impossible to search them by their properties values

Comment: Yes while I currently don't need that facility I might in the future. If I subclass and use annotations I basically have to override all getters and setters and all private members too; they will not be persisted as the class is not marked as an entity. Looks like there is no easy way to achieve this.

Comment: @Kerry you don't have to set up private members again, you can use wrapper like this `@Column("PROP_A") void setPropA(int a) { super.setPropA(a); }`