# How to create a hibernate entity from an external api class?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm writing in game engine API so i haven't direct access to classes and i can't add hibernate annotations (@Entity, @Table etc.) but i must save this class from API in my object (table). How can i do this? Extends API object and create new with hibernate annotations or parse this object to string? Any ideas?

Class for example what i mean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="location")
    private Location locationOfPlayer; // - this is the class from API

}
```

Comment: You need mapping for this class. Other solution would be to serialize and save in that form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persisting 3rd party objects with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306438/persisting-3rd-party-objects-with-jpa)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a mapping file for this, which you need to define in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0" ...>
   <persistence-unit name="database">
       <mapping-file>mapping.xml</mapping-file>
       ...
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In your mapping file you can define ORM mappings even for third party classes:

```
<entity-mappings version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd">
    <package>thirdparty</package>
    <entity class="Location" name="Location">
        ...
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: The correct answer IMO. If the JPA spec itself allows for handling such cases then why introduce something else. There is more info in Chapter 12 *Object/Relational Mapping Descriptor* of the JPA 2.1 Spec

Answer (score 0):

The only realistic/good way to do this is by `Instrumentation`.
You might want to create and apply a `Java Agent`, which transform the desired classes at load time, adding the JPA annotations. That's basically bytecode modification.

See for example, [ClassFileTransformer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html).

Comment: that is very interesting, did not know this existed. now practically speaking is this better solution than creating a wrapper class for desired entity instead. i would think this is not very upgradable as it is very version dependent.

Comment: @Shawn well, it is an opinion-based decision. Personally I don't like polluting my packages with "wrapper" classes. And just think about it, every time you need an interaction between the API class (the plain class)  and your service/repository, you need to wrap it. Maybe you can centralize that, maybe not. Honestly the ClassFileTransformer-way is much more appealing to me. I can maintain it as a separate module/project. What do you mean with version dependant?

Comment: @Shawn I'd also add that, speaking about permormance and memory optimization, this approach cannot be beaten.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. i'll have to try it in one my projects and become more familiar with this API.

Comment: @Shawn try it out. It's a very powerful mechanism. You can do beautiful things with it. Just search for "load time weaving - Aspect oriented programming"

Comment: While this may be *a* solution it is clearly not  *the only realistic/good way to do this*. See the answer by @Tobias Liefke

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're going to have to duplicate the data in your entity classes: i.e. create entities with similar fields and persist those rather than using the API classes. This has the downside that you'll manually need to keep your data model up to date, but the upside is that changes in the API won't break your database code directly.

Once you're done duplicating the data you can use a mapping framework (I rather like Mapstruct because it does the mapping at compile time, but runtime libraries such as Orika are also quite popular for this task)